# Redis on Java Connection Pool

Tags: redis, jedis

I am new to Redis and currently using Java 8, Java EE 7 and AWS Elastic Cache on Redis. 
Using my java knowledge, all resources should be closed/returned to the pool once the task is over.

```
pool= new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(),"myendpoint.aws.com",6379,Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
try(Jedis jedis=pool.getResource();)
{
    ListTask gt=new ListTask();
    JsonArray listofTask=gt.getTutorials();
    Map<String,String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("ListofTask",listofTask.toString());
    jedis.hmset(key, attributes);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RedisOperation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,"setRedisListofTaskJSON", ex);
}
pool.close();
```

On clicking info, i get Connected clients as 149. This is just one box testing the application multiple times. And each time the connected_clients are increasing and memory is increasing.

Clients
connected_clients:149
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

Question : 
**1 How to close/house keep connections?** 
**2 How to set an age/ttl on key?**

Using JDK8, Java EE7 and Redis 2.8(using Jedis to connect).

Answer (score 1):

Since I used try-resources, there is no need to close jedis pool resource. At the end of the application, destory the pool by calling destroy method.

```
try(Jedis jedis=pool.getResource();)
{    
    jedis.hmset(key, attributes);
}catch (Exception ex) {

}
pool.destroy();
```

Original documentation 
https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your question 2 is using expire or expireat and ttl methods from [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.java) class